# C Adding each char into array

Tags: c

For C++ - I can add each `char` to each index in `string` array:

```
   string *x=new string[10];
    x[0] += "a";
    x[0] += "b";
    x[0] += "c";
    x[1] += "x";
    x[1] += "y";
    x[1] += "z";
    cout << "x[0]=" << x[0] << endl; // would be "abc"
    cout << "x[1]=" << x[1] << endl; // would be "xyz"
```

How can I do same functionality in C? I have `buff2` pointer to a `char` array and am trying to add `char` value from each index of `buf`. I keep getting weird values when I print out `buff2` value.

```
char buf[255];
char *buff2;
int i=0, count=0;
buff2=(char*)malloc(512*sizeof(char));

  while((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf[g]))) > 0){
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
      if(buf[i] == '\n'){
        l++;
        count2++;
      }
       else
     {   
       buff2[count2]+=buf[i];
     }
  }
```

Comment: having *a* and *b* being `std::string` the equivalent of `a+=b;` in C can be `strcat(a,b);`is C ... supposing *a* enough long. You use lib in C++ why not using lib too in C ? If needed you can increase result string length using `realloc`

Comment: First off, what is this: ```l++```? This is an L, not an i. Also, it seems you are adding char values together in an array - you are not concatenating strings when you do ```buff2[count2]+=buf[i];```.

Comment: Create an array of pointers, for each location as suggested use `realloc` and `strcat(a,b)` and you can then print the pointers using `%s`.

Comment: `read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf[g]))` in the best case reads only one char into `buf[0]`, what interrest to have an array of 255 ?

Comment: warning @MohitSharma `print the pointers using %s` is wrong, that format write the contains of a (supposed) string, use %p for a pointer

Comment: @bruno I mean print the data at that location using `%s` like `ptr` having value of `0xabcde` pointing to some data at location.

Comment: _"I keep getting weird values when I print out buff2 value."_. Please show how exactly you print those buff2 values. Show a [MCVE] as well as an example of input, and expected and actual output.

Comment: Your `c++` example is not adding a `char` to strings. It is appending strings to strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems in your C code

- *buff* is an array for nothing  because you only use `buff[0]`
- the variable *l* seems never defined/initialized, and you modify it for nothing
- `buff2[count2]+=buf[i];` always modify the same `buff2[count2]` until a newline because you do not increase *buff2* in that case but only when reading a newline, are you sure you want that ?
- you do not end *buff2* with a null character, that probably explain *I keep getting weird values when I print out buff2 value.*
- you do not have a protection in case you write out of *buff2* producing an undefined behavior

---

> ```
> string *x=new string[10];
> ```

can be in C

```
char ** x = calloc(10, sizeof(char *));
```

I use *calloc* to initialize with null pointers

and an equivalent of :

> ```
> x[0] += "a";
> ```

can be

```
 strCat(&x[0], "a");
```

with:

```
char * const strCat(char ** p, const char * s)
{
   if (s != NULL) {
     if (*p == NULL)
       *p = strdup(s);
     else { 
       size_t len = strlen(*p);

       *p = realloc(*p, len + strlen(s) + 1); /* may be detect realloc returns NULL on error */
       strcpy(*p + len, s);
     }
   }

   return *p;
}
```

So for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * const strCat(char ** p, const char * s)
{
   if (s != NULL) {
     if (*p == NULL)
       *p = strdup(s);
     else { 
       size_t len = strlen(*p);

       *p = realloc(*p, len + strlen(s) + 1); /* may be detect realloc returns NULL on error */
       strcpy(*p + len, s);
     }
   }

   return *p;
}

int main()
{
  char ** x = calloc(10, sizeof(char *));

  strCat(&x[0], "a");
  strCat(&x[0], "b");
  strCat(&x[0], "c");
  
  strCat(&x[1], "x");
  strCat(&x[1], "y");
  strCat(&x[1], "z");
  
  printf("x[0]=%s\n", x[0]);
  printf("x[1]=%s\n", x[1]);
  
  free(x[0]);
  free(x[1]);
  free(x);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
% gcc -Wall a.c
% ./a.out
x[0]=abc
x[1]=xyz
%
```

Running under *valgrind*:

```
% valgrind ./a.out
==113490== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==113490== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==113490== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==113490== Command: ./a.out
==113490== 
x[0]=abc
x[1]=xyz
==113490== 
==113490== HEAP SUMMARY:
==113490==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==113490==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 98 bytes allocated
==113490== 
==113490== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==113490== 
==113490== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==113490== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
%
```

Note however each time you concatenate a new string it is needed to go through the current string to know its length, this is not done by  `std::string` whose knows the used length whatever the way for that, as this is the case in the answer of KamilCuk

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do same functionality in C?

First implement/invent a "string".

After that you can implement the functionality. Remember about proper error handling. I just used `abort()` for brevity below, in normal code destructors should be run.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct string {
    char *begin;
    char *end;
    size_t free;
} string;
void string_init(string *t) {
   t->begin = t->end = NULL;
   t->free = 0;
}
void string_fini(string *t) {
   free(t->begin);
}
// iadd convention from python
int string_iadd_cstr(string *t, const char *str) {
   const size_t addlen = strlen(str);
   if (t->free < addlen + 1) {
       const size_t curlen = t->end - t->begin;
       const size_t newlen = curlen + 1 + addlen;
       void *tmp = realloc(t->begin, newlen);
       if (tmp == NULL) {
           return -1;
       }
       t->begin = tmp;
       t->end = t->begin + curlen;
       t->free = newlen - curlen;
   }
   memcpy(t->end, str, addlen + 1);
   t->end += addlen;
   t->free -= addlen;
   return 0;
}
int string_print(string *t) {
    return printf("%s", t->begin);
}

int main() {
    // string *x=new string[10];
    string *x = malloc(10 * sizeof(*x));
    if (x == NULL) abort();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        string_init(&x[i]);
    }

    if (string_iadd_cstr(&x[0], "a")) abort();
    if (string_iadd_cstr(&x[0], "b")) abort();
    if (string_iadd_cstr(&x[0], "c")) abort();
    if (string_iadd_cstr(&x[1], "x")) abort();
    if (string_iadd_cstr(&x[1], "y")) abort();
    if (string_iadd_cstr(&x[1], "z")) abort();

    // cout << "x[0]=" << x[0] << endl;
    printf("%s", "x[0]=");
    string_print(&x[0]);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    // cout << "x[1]=" << x[1] << endl;
    printf("%s", "x[1]=");
    string_print(&x[1]);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    // run destructors
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        string_fini(&x[i]);
    }
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: so strange your answer was not UV, too complicated for non C++ user ? So I do ;-)

Comment: Two comments: Poster needs to add a `char` to a string, even if his `c++` example is appending a string. It is typically not needed to allocate more space than you need, just do a `realloc` on each append. In *extreme* cases (tyny increments/huge buffer) you may get a maximum of 10x speedup doing pre-allocation. Unless you are not working with strings in a tight loop, that is not worth the extra complexity

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example if you do not want to use `strcat`. This is a minimal example to demonstrate how one could concatenate strings, things like reallocation of memory have not been implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char buf[30] = "LOREM \n IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET\0";
    char *buff2;
    int i = 0, n = 30;
    buff2 = (char*)malloc(512 * sizeof(char));

    //set first element of buff2 to be terminating null char
    buff2[0] = '\0';
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(buf[i] != '\n') {    
            buff2[i + 1] = '\0'; // shift terminating null char forward
            buff2[i] = buf[i];
        } else {
            buff2[i + 1] = '\0'; // shift terminating null char forward
            buff2[i] = 'n';
        }
    }
    
    printf("%s\n",buff2);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It replaces newlines with an "n" character; you can change this if you want. Of course, you want to be careful only to address elements which have actually been allocated. Does not include function to read from file because we don't have the file; this is easily implemented. I suggest you look into `fgetc`.

Comment: You are forgetting to realloc whatever `buff2` is pointing at. The fact that the poster is doing multiple reads of 512 bytes, is a hint that he wants to be able to end up with more than 512 bytes.

Comment: "Of course, you want to be careful only to address elements which have actually been allocated." It is a minimal example. My answer also doesn't include the filestream. OP wanted to know how to concatenate strings - this is an answer to that question. I even included a warning concerning memory allocation.

Comment: Yes, you did show him "a way to concatenate strings", except that in c, there is no best way to do it. Concatenating when you know the buffer is large enough, and concatenating with buffer resize is totally different. Based on the context the poster provided, he obviously wanted the latter. He asked for something similar to to `std::string` `+=`,  and had no explicit limit of 512 bytes.

Comment: Ok, I think this is some kind of misunderstanding. I get your point. I may or may not have misunderstood OP's question. What I felt was most important was the string concatenation. I still feel my answer provides value here because it is the shortest one. I am also thinking about people who will read this in the future, who may only want to know about the strings, not the memory.